# Why isn't the element getting the transition in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions

I have a box here that I want it to get the `translateX(300px)` with the 2000ms `transition`, meaning it should be moved with a transition, but it's not getting to move *with* the transition, it just gets the `transform` property immediately with no `transition`, and I don't know why, how can I make it to move with the transition declared in JavaScript?

```js
document.getElementById('1box').style.transition = 'all 1000ms';
document.getElementById('1box').style.transform = 'translateX(300px)';
```

```css
*{
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        div{
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin: auto;
            transition: 1000ms;
        }
```

```html
<div id="1box"></div>
```

Comment: Can't you just have `transition` property already there and only update `transform` in JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `onload` function of the `window`, and put all styling inside the function.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('1box').style.transition = 'all 1000ms';
  document.getElementById('1box').style.transform = 'translateX(300px)';
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="1box"></div>
```

Comment: @Dorothy Please check if it helps. Feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Although it is allowed in HTML 5 to start ids with digits, i'd recommend against it (`<div id="1box"></div>`). Sometimes it may weirdly fail in browsers (when adding this answer, it failed both in CSS and JavaScript - using Chrome 90 on Ubuntu).
2. Also, as @TechySharnav answered, place your code into a `window.onload` event. This will make sure that your code is executed after the document is loaded (you have the DOM already built).
3. A much better approach is to use classes (this removes styling from your JavaScript code and have everything in one spot, your CSS file). Also, classes can be just as easily removed as you add them, and you can perform a reverse animation as well.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.querySelector('#box1').classList.add('right-sidebar');
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: auto;
  transition: all 2s;
}

.right-sidebar{
  transform: translate(300px);
  transition: all 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="box1"></div>
```

Comment: Well, I used `window.onload` in my answer...but it is OK...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (fixed).

Answer (score 0):

Add the transition property on the element via css.

```
#lbox {
    transition: transform 2s;
}
```

or reverse the order of your `js` declaration:

```
document.getElementById('1box').style.transition = 'transform 2s';
document.getElementById('1box').style.transform = 'translateX(300px)';
```

Comment: transition property doesn't work in all opera browser: [Can i use it?](https://caniuse.com/css-transitions)

Comment: Thanks @SimoneRossaini, can I add this addition info on my answer?

Comment: @jpneey I tried both of your solutions, none worked.

Comment: Why `all` if all they want to animate is `transform`?

Comment: Updated my answer. It's just a bad habit of mine @RoboRobok

Comment: @RoboRobok Even trying that, doesn't work.

Comment: @jpneey yes you can